# Catch user error and re-enable application.events after error

Tags: excel, vba

Amateur coder asking for help, again :-)

I have the below code that works good, it gets a variable from a drop down validation list and executes command automatically because I and using the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`. The issue I have is that sometimes the user types into the box rather then select it.

I get a

> run-time error 91

because it cannot find the value typed in by user.

How can I catch this error and make a message popup to tell them they must choose from drop down list? And Also since it breaks the code it sets my `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` since it doesn't finish the code from the `ByVal Target As Range` section that resets to `True`.

How can I reset the `Application.EnableEvents` to `True` in the event of a code break?

```
Sub Copy_From_Borrower_DBase()
    Dim myVal As String
    Dim sourceRng As Range
    myVal = Sheets("Main").Range("F2").Value ' dropdown list
    Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Borrower Database").Range("5:5").Find(What:=myVal, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'locate column where to copy from
    Worksheets("Main").Range("F5").Value = Worksheets("Borrower Database").Cells(5, sourceRng.Column).Value 'Borrower Name
    Worksheets("Main").Range("G6").Value = Worksheets("Borrower Database").Cells(6, sourceRng.Column).Value 'Income
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check first that the range does not return Nothing (meaning the term was not found). The use of With is basically cosmetic, but I think tidies up the code somewhat.

```
Sub Copy_From_Borrower_DBase()

Dim myVal As String
Dim sourceRng As Range
myVal = Sheets("Main").Range("F2").Value ' dropdown list

With Worksheets("Borrower Database")
    Set sourceRng = .Range("5:5").Find(What:=myVal, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not sourceRng Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Main").Range("F5").Value = .Cells(5, sourceRng.Column).Value 'Borrower Name"
        Worksheets("Main").Range("G6").Value = .Cells(6, sourceRng.Column).Value 'Income"
    Else
        MsgBox "whatever"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this worked great, can you help me with code to see if record exists and if so a msgbox to indicate YES or NO?

Comment: Quite possibly. Is this a separate question?

Comment: Ummm yeah I guess it is, should I post a new question? and mark this one as answered by you?

Comment: Yes, I think that's probably best if you are asking a whole new question. Thanks.

Comment: Whilst this may handle the error it doesn't really answer the question on how to catch the error and how to re-enable events after

Comment: No but the error shouldn't now arise. Peh's answer covers the error angle I think.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question about error handling:

```
Public Sub MyProcedure()
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Goto ENABLE_EVENTS 'if any error occurs after this line events get enabled.

    'stuff where an error could occur

ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "an error occurred"
    End If
End Sub
```

For more information about error handling: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Comment: Where do I place this code and do I have to call it from every Sub?

Comment: Everything you need to know about error handling is in that guide. Actually this is an **example** how you can use `EnableEvents = False` in your procedure and ensure it will always be re-enabled if an error occurs. That's nothing you can call from your sub, that's a how you do it in your sub.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to solve the problem by not allowing there to be a problem, if that fails then worry about error handling.

Since you are already calling Worksheet_Change and using Data Validation, this checks the value of the validation cell.  If it has a value in it then your code will run.  If it is empty it will not.  Data Validation clears the cell if someone types in it, so no matter what they type by the time it hits Worksheet_Change it should be an empty string.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then         ' Your Dropdown Validation Cell
        If Not Target.Value = "" Then
            Call Copy_From_Borrower_DBase
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```