# Worksheet Event Not Firing

Tags: excel, vba

My basic worksheet event code is not working.

I have the following code included in my Sheet4 workbook (where I want it to run):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Target.Column = 14 Then
    ThisRow = Target.Row
    If Target.Value = "In Progress" Then
        Range("S" & ThisRow).Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    End If
End If 
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5
End Sub
```

-This is in my "Sheet 4" Project (i.e. when I click right click on the tab and click "View Code", it pulls directly into the vba and I see my code there)

-I have checked my trust center and all macros are enabled. The sheet is saved on my desktop, so it should be a trusted location.

I have no idea why neither of the above code blocks are working. When I have an executable macro clicked, that works (i.e. do this when I tell this macro to run).

Finally, this excel is saved as a macro enabled workbook.

Comment: This event `Worksheet_Change2`  does not exist in Excel and therefore will never fire. You cannot change the names of events.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change2` does not work because it's not an event handler. How do you know `Worksheet_Change` does not work?

Comment: I find that the events often don't fire after an error has occurred (and also sometimes seemingly at random). The only way I have found to restart the events is to completely close and restart Excel.

Comment: @Gravitate If events don't fire after an error occurs then this is probably because someone used `Application.EnableEvents = False` without a correct error handling that re-activates it in case of error. • I have never discovered non-fired events after errors in Excel.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Ah, Thanks! I'll check for that.

Comment: @Gravitate see [Catch user error and re-enable application.events after error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53395180)

Comment: @Jonathan Make 100% sure your event does not run by adding a breakpoint or a massage box like `MsgBox "I run"` as first line in the event's code. Then write something to a cell in the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Dim ThisRow As Long

    If Target.Column = 14 And Target.Value = "In Progress" Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        Range("S" & ThisRow).Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5
    End If

End Sub
```

This worked fine for me. Get used to develop using `Option Explicit`because it will force you to declare all your variables and that is the way to avoid errors.

Comment: If the OP's code does not work, your code won't either.

Comment: @GSerg I put his 2 procedures on the same, if he means the font color wont change, this solves it. If he wants everything changed on the sheet changing the font color, taking the line out of the conditional will do too.

Comment: @Damian I don't think the OP is saying that his code isn't working correctly. I think he is saying that the event isn't firing at all, irrelevant of what code is in the event handler. Or at least that is how I read it.

Comment: The OP is saying neither of the two handlers work. That means this united handler will not work either, because there is something else that prevents the otherwise correctly looking `Worksheet_Change` from firing.

Comment: May he be waiting for the color procedure because the time is already there but he didn't notice? Anyway until he give us further info can't do much else. If this doesn't help i'll delete the answer.